# On Ubuntu 20.04 getting loop when try to login, and on terminal always getting "Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at" msg

Tags: command-line, apt, 20.04, package-management, python

Whenever I try to run any command as like `ls` or `sudo` etc. I am getting below error and I won't able to login to my system.
(Note : I have seen multiple answers for this questions but non is worked for me that's why I have added new question)

**Error message** :

```
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:

https:bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.3
Python version: 3.8.10 final 0
Exception information:

unable to open database file
Trackback(most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 23, in crash_guard
callback()
File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 90 in main
cnf =  CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound(options.data_dir)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 79, in _init__
self.db = SqliteDatabase(dbpath)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 12, in __init__
self.con = sqlite3.connect(filename)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Comment: I was trying to install flutter setup on my system and I was following steps from below link 
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-path-directly
and as per instructions I edit /etc/profile file and reboot the system, but after reboot 
I stuck into login loop, that's why I tried with terminal(by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3) and  whenever I try to run any command I got error with above lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quiet sure, the last edit of `/etc/profile` introduced a syntax error there.

- Try using another shell after login, like `dash`
- If it does not work, go to recovery console (shift at grub menu, and select advanced)
- If no success yet, anyway as last resort, use boot-able USB and fix it.

Comment: Able to solve the problem using second option.